# STAssertEqualObjects can I check for two accepted values?

Tags: ios, macos, unit-testing

I'd like to unit test an `NSString` for it's value, but I need to be able to accept two "correct" values. not just one. How would I do this ?

I know I can do something like:

```
STAssertEqualObjects(node.name, @"attachment", @"invalid name");
```

But how do I accept, for example, `@"attachment"` AND `@"table"` values as correct and not fail the unit test if the `NSString` equals to either one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no macro specifically for that.  You could use `STAssertTrue` and an `NSArray` literal containing the acceptable values:

```
STAssertTrue([@([@"attachment", @"table"]) containsObject:myString]), @"invalid name");
```

You need an extra pair of parentheses to hide the comma from the macro preprocessor that handles `STAssertTrue`.

Or you could just spell it out:

```
STAssertTrue([@"attachment" isEqual:node.name] || [@"table" isEqual:node.name], @"invalid name");
```

Comment: cool! the first example didn't work like written, but after I created the NSArray on a separate line and then asserted it, it worked. The second example worked just like that. thank you!

Comment: The first example should work if you are using Xcode 4.5 or later.

Comment: I have Xcode 4.5.1 but it doesn't like that syntax for some reason.

Comment: @radvan72 I figured out the problem.  I have updated my answer.